# Open Office Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation, openoffice-calc

I have searched for the answer, but honestly am not finding any answers. I am creating a spreadsheet where there is a Data Validation string, for this example we will use a list of shirt manufacturers. So I make a drop down list for Gildan, Fruit of the Loom, American Apparel, etc.. When the user picks a certain manufacturer (for instance Gildan), I want the next drop down menu to have a list of the styles of shirts (2000, 5000, etc.). Is this possible with Excel, or in my case Open Office?

Comment: Definitely possible, but first where is the data coming from? Also I'm not sure why you are calling this validation?

Comment: The data is coming from created lists. I am calling it validation because it's the closest thing I have found for it to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize the data where the manufacturers are headers and below each header is the data for the second list.
Then for the first cell drop down set the Validity to cell range and choose the row that has all the headers.
In the second cell set the validity to cell range, and in the source field enter
`OFFSET({the column of data under the first manufacturer};0;MATCH({the first cell};{the headers range})-1)`
[image: Example]